# Realm swift with API calls

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm relatively new to realm and have just started researching about it and playing around it , one thing I noticed is you everything is based on Realm Object Server and that is the heart of it. My question is that if one wants to use this with normal sqlite backend server with custom API calls, for eg Login API call of my own choosing, how would one go about it ? Should that be the flow of the app i.e My app - Realm Server - My custom backend , or backend end server should not be in the picture , I know we can install realm backend on our server but its still realm object server. If that is not the flow then how can I make backend calls using realm. I know some of my doubts must be naive but I would like to clear my doubts about this as fast as possible as this is a very interesting technology.